# Get word under cursor in X11

Tags: scripts, xorg, automation, xdotool

For some scripting, I need to get the word currently under the cursor.

Can `xdotool` or a similar tool get it?

Comment: Do you mean *selected* word? Then yes. (But not xdotool)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### How to get the currently *selected* text

You can get the currently *selected* text with the command:

```
echo $(xclip -o -sel)
```

...but you'd need to install `xclip` first:

```
sudo apt-get install xclip
```

From `man xclip`:

```
-o, -out
    prints the selection to standard out (generally for piping to a file or program)
```

and:

```
-selection
    specify which X selection to use, options are "primary" to use XA_PRIMARY (default), "secondary" for XA_SECONDARY or "clipboard" for XA_CLIPBOARD
```

See also [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xclip) or, as always, `man xclip`.

---

### EDIT

#### Workaround issues with the last selection

From a comment, I understood that `xclip` outputs the *last* selection, even if there is nothing selected anymore (e.g. when the file is closed). That seems to be an issue in your situation.

Although `xsel` also has this issue, it can be worked around: if we make your script not only read the current selection into the script, but *also* write the same content to a file. We can then check if a the *new* selection is different from the last selection. If not, we can conclude no new selection is made, and the command most likely produces an outdated selection. We can then tell the script to pass.

An example (using `xsel`, which has slight advantages in this case):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# make sure the file to store the last selection exists
f=~/.old_sel
touch $f
# get the previous & current selection
old=$(cat "$f"); new=$(xsel -o)

if [ "$old" != "$new" ]; then
  # if selection changed, store the new selection to remember
  echo "$new" > "$f"
  # do the action, whatever that may be
  echo $new
fi
```

No need to say that you'd need to install `xsel`:

```
sudo apt-get install xsel
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without selection?

Comment: @BharadwajRaju That would really surprise me, what is the current application to communicate with? You wouldn't know! It would require some global text recognition on what happens on the screen. And even then..I don't see it happen.

Comment: Is there a way to find if there is any text currently selected? Because even if there isn't any, `xclip` returns the *last* selected text.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju see my update.

Comment: Sometimes (randomly) it returns `Error: Target STRING not available` and exits.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju in tge second version?

Comment: No, just `xclip -o sel`

Comment: It doesn't update/clears out selection if I select a word with Ctrl+Shift+<--